# jquery ajax request resulting in IllegalStateException: getOutputStream()

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jackson

I have a spring portlet mvc application. I have a jsp which uses an Ajax request to make a GET request to a resource URL which then uses Spring Jackson mapper(MappingJacksonJsonView) class to return json. The GET request is pretty slow and can take a couple of seconds to execute. I noticed a use case;

1. I click the AJAX submitting link in my application
2. I refresh the page before the request completes
3. I repeat above step
4. My server logs starting throwing illegalstatexception

   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:611)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:198)
   at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:112)

Because Spring is responsible for creating and deleting the output reader and writers i can't catch the illegalexception SO i'm finding it difficult to isolate where the exact issue is occuring.

any suggestions or help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer - The following was happening. I think i can put it down to a low impact issue.

It happens when the browser opens a Socket and makes an Ajax request however it then terminates the open Socket (by closing the browser or moving to another page) before receiving the response from the server. Meanwhile the server is processing the request and tries to write the output back to the browser however the browser has closed the Socket and moved on.